# Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, diagnostic-tools

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 and I was playing with Diagnostic Tools. suddenly, after some restarts, the window does not open anymore and I don't figure out how to do it. Anyone knows how can I open it again ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The selection is a bit hidden, it's in Debug, Windows, Show Diagnostic Tools. It should be with other window settings really to be easily found.

Comment: Thank you :-) Exactly where you said !

Comment: Given how many entries merging the Debug | Windows sub-menu into the  View menu would add when debugging, splitting the many debug tool windows out is probably a good idea. Albeit not discoverable. On the other hand: quick find.

Comment: @Richard It would bring one extra item, since it would be in a submenu, or at least they could be in the Other Windows section. But yeah, Quick Launch also works fine.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks you're a life saver!!

Comment: not there :( and quick launch doesnt suggest anything either

Comment: I was able to add it, but was not to be enabled until the next time I debug

Answer (score 24):

I just searched for hours for the Diagnostic Tools and did not find them in Visual Studio 2017. There was no menu entry in Debug --> Windows for me.

Finally, I wrote 'Diagnostics' into the Quick Launch bar and Visual Studio offered me to install this missing feature... I guess I forgot to check the tools on first installation!

Comment: It appears to be buried under Debug > Performance Profiler in now. (Although network is missing)

Comment: @Reahreic Performance Profiler and Diagnostics Tools are two different things.

Comment: Note that this also works if you have it installed. Except you should write "Diagnostic" in Quick Launch, not "Diagnostics".

Answer (score 2):

If you're after a hotkey, the Diagnostic Tools can be reopened by default by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+F2**.

Answer (score 0):

For other people struggling to find this. Microsoft might have changed how to open the Diagnostics window. Currently for Visual Studio 2019 I went to **Debug** > **Intellitrace** to open the missing Diagnostic window.